# Single line Ace editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm trying to set up an Ace editor with only one single line of text.

The idea is to mimic the behaviour of an `<input type="text">` box, but with syntax colouring:
[image]

Currently if the user presses `Enter` while in the editor, it creates a new line:
[image]

So my question is:

#### How can I set up Ace to allow one single line only, like a standard text input box?

Below is what I've tried so far, and the reasons why it didn't succeed.

- **Calling `editor.undo()` on `change` if `e.lines.length > 1`**

  The problem is, `change` gets triggered *before* the actual change is applied in the deltas, so the `undo()` doesn't work here (or it concerns the previous delta)
- **Cancelling `keypress` if `Event.which = 13`**

  It kind of works but is very dirty, and it does not handle the case where multiple-lines text is pasted, so we'd need to handle `paste` event as well - which would make this solution even dirtier. I'm also pretty confident there would be even more edge cases to take into account.
- **Trying to "empty" `e` in `on("change", function(e) { ... })`**

  For instance, saying that `e = {}` in the callback function, provided that `e` is just a reference to the actual object. No effect whatsoever.
- **Trying to find a built-in parameter in Ace editor to do that**

  No success in finding such a parameter yet...

Comment: `e` is a reference, so changing it wont affect the original event. Have you tried just modifying whichever property on `e` holds the new text?

Comment: Sounds like you should list for the Enter event on the element and cancel it, it is not dirty as you are wanting to stop Enter being used. On paste, just stripe the line separators out of the string and the end user will catch on pretty quick. I don't see much more edge cases than typing/pasting.

Comment: Strip out newlines when loading the element; keypress handler seems right. Coincidentally I am doing something similar w/ a different editor component.

Comment: @DaveNewton that is what I end up doing in the fiddle. For some reason stopPropagation and preventDefault doesnt work

Comment: Thanks to all. It appears that if `change` effectively gets triggered *before* the delta is inserted in the `undo` chain, it's nevertheless triggered *after* the change has been made into the editor - so @vittore 's solution works like a charm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason neither `e.preventDefault` nor `e.stopPropagation` works in change event handler. But you can do find-replace.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/3rLfdtxb/

```
 var editor = ace.edit("editor");
 editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
 editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
 editor.setFontSize(30)
 editor.getSession().on('change', function(e) {
    console.log(e)
    if (e.data.text.charCodeAt(0) === 10 && e.data.action == "insertText") {
      console.log('cancel event')
      //e.preventDefault() // doesnt work
      //e.stopPropagation()  // doesnt work
      editor.find(String.fromCharCode(10))
      editor.replaceAll(''); // this work
    }
 })
```

You can even remove `if` statement from handler and replace line break on any change, regardless.

When you find-replace in change, you got line from cursor to the end of line selected. In order to deselect it after that use :

```
editor.selection.clearSelection()
```

Comment: Making a change inside the change event causes an issue in the worker for me.  And it seems that the change event structure has changed since this answer.  I'll post the code that works for me as another answer.

Answer (score 14):

you can use the following code to make editor behave similar to input type="text" (mostly taken from https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.0/demo/kitchen-sink/layout.js#L103)

```js
var el = document.getElementById("textbox")
var editor = ace.edit(el);
editor.setOptions({
    maxLines: 1, // make it 1 line
    autoScrollEditorIntoView: true,
    highlightActiveLine: false,
    printMargin: false,
    showGutter: false,
    mode: "ace/mode/javascript",
    theme: "ace/theme/tomorrow_night_eighties"
});
// remove newlines in pasted text
editor.on("paste", function(e) {
    e.text = e.text.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, " ");
});
// make mouse position clipping nicer
editor.renderer.screenToTextCoordinates = function(x, y) {
    var pos = this.pixelToScreenCoordinates(x, y);
    return this.session.screenToDocumentPosition(
        Math.min(this.session.getScreenLength() - 1, Math.max(pos.row, 0)),
        Math.max(pos.column, 0)
    );
};
// disable Enter Shift-Enter keys
editor.commands.bindKey("Enter|Shift-Enter", "null")
```

```css
#textbox {
    font-size: 30px;
    border:solid 2px gray;
}
body{
   background: #161619;
   padding: 40px 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js"></script>


<div id=textbox>var a = 1</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of the existing answer where very helpful in getting this working for me, but I still encountered some issues I had to address (some apparently due to api changes).  This is the combination of both answers that is working for me.

**Note**, when you run these snippets or a jsFiddle for example, a CORS check will prevent the worker from loading so, just because the example "works" doesn't mean it will all work when integrated into your project.

Also note... this is react code using hooks, but the basic code should apply.

It also uses resizing code from [Set width of ace editor instance according to the length of characters in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57274039/set-width-of-ace-editor-instance-according-to-the-length-of-characters-in-it)

```
const editDiv = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (editing) {
      if (!editor && editDiv.current) {
        editDiv.current.textContent = value;
        const ed = ace.edit(editDiv.current);
        ed.setOptions({
          maxLines: 1,
          autoScrollEditorIntoView: true,
          highlightActiveLine: false,
          printMargin: false,
          showGutter: false,
          enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
          enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
          enableSnippets: false,
          mode: "ace/mode/javascript",
          theme: "ace/theme/tomorrow_night_eighties"
        });
        ed.commands.bindKey(
          "Up|Ctrl-P|Down|Ctrl-N|PageUp|PageDown",
          "null"
        );
        ed.commands.addCommand({
          name: "SaveOnEnter",
          bindKey: {
            win: "Enter",
            mac: "Enter",
            sender: "editor|cli"
          },
          exec: () => {
            setValue(ed.getValue());
            // Handle new value;
          }
        });
        ed.on("paste", e => {
          e.text = e.text.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, " ");
        });
        setEditor(ed);

        ed.getSession().on("change", e => {
          if (e.action == "insert" && ed.session.getValue().includes("\n")) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              // doing a replaceAll during a change event causes issues in the
              // worker, so we'll queue up the change
              ed.find(String.fromCharCode(10));
              ed.replaceAll("");
              ed.selection.clearSelection();
            }, 0);
          }
        });
        ed.renderer.on("beforeRender", (e, renderer) => {
          const rSession = renderer.session;
          const text = rSession.getLine(0);
          const charCount = rSession.$getStringScreenWidth(text)[0];
          const width =
            Math.max(charCount, 2) * renderer.characterWidth + // text size
            2 * renderer.$padding + // padding
            2 + // little extra for the cursor
            0; // add border width if needed

          renderer.container.style.width = width + "px";
          renderer.onResize(false, 0, width, renderer.$size.height);
        });
        ed.setWrapBehavioursEnabled(false);
        ed.session.setUseWrapMode(false);
        ed.focus();
      }
    } else {
      if (editor) {
        editor.renderer.on("beforeRender", () => {});
        editor.destroy();
        setEditor(undefined);
      }
    }
  }, [editing]);

  return <div ref={editDiv} style={{ width: "1em", height: "1.2em" }} />;
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what i was looking for. I've used only the on("change") callback - suits to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try provide `maxLines` set to `1` in the `setOptions` property.
I use `react-ace` version `9.2.0`.
I use this as an optional/configurable behavior, with an exposed property on wrapper component:
`maxLines={this.props.singleLine ? 1 : undefined}`